# How do I save a web page in Firefox - the saved version shows "view previous comments" again

Tags: firefox, backup, html, browser-cache

I am trying to save a page with Firefox.  It's a post on facebook, loaded on its own page. I clicked "view previous comments" so all comments are displayed. I save the page.

I then loaded the saved file.  "View previous comments" is back, and if I click on it it wants to load the source off of the internet.  I tried loading the page again, displaying all the comments again, switching Firefox to offline mode, and saving the page.  I got three consecutive "source could not be read" errors.  It saved part of it anyway.  I loaded the page, and again, "view previous comments" is back.  I tried "view page source" from the completely loaded page, and then saved the file from that window, and I get exactly the same results.

Firefox 20.0.1; Windows XP SP3.

Comment: The comments are probably being loaded on demand using AJAX when you click the load link. It's not going to be that easy to save them. Related: [Get Current HTML Of Page Built With AJAX Requests](http://superuser.com/questions/414198/get-current-html-of-page-built-with-ajax-requests).

Comment: If all you need is a screen shot, have you seen [How can you take a screenshot of an entire webpage?](http://superuser.com/questions/216823/how-can-you-take-a-screenshot-of-an-entire-webpage?lq=1) yet?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to do the same using the "Print Edit" add-on in FF and it seems to provide what you want.

In FB expand the comments and click on the print Edit option "Print Edit" - you can then remove the sections you don't want and save the remaining as a Firefox HTML doc. 
Alternatively edit the page and print it out. 
Note that you can't save from the Print Preview screen.

I run Windows 7 but it's a Firefox function so should work for you

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/print-edit/