# How to save down currently displayed HTML page - Firefox?

Tags: firefox, html, firefox-extensions

I have a webpage that I need to save down. I load the page with AutoPager.
But saving large pages loaded with AutoPager just won't work. (see [my Q](https://superuser.com/questions/619652/cannot-save-down-page-thats-been-loaded-by-autopager))

**What I see** on the page would be perfect (in HTML, that is).
I tried the "Inspect Element" and Firebug's tool as well, but they are not the same as I would save down the page with CTRL+S.

I also tried:

- Installing Firefox on Linux - nope.
- Try DownThemAll on the loaded
  pages - nope.
- Install Nightly - nope.
- Install Firefox on a RamDisk - nope.
- Try 64-bit Firefox - nope.
- Try loading the rule into AutoPage/Chrome (it won't do anything) - nope.

Selenium would be great for example, but it can't save.

(Also, I would need to page on the file. Like Open the page, Save page, Click next, Save page, Click next, Save page, so on, so on.)

Comment: What do you mean save *down* as in you want the source? Or do you need something like a [web clipper](http://evernote.com/webclipper/) to save the page as is

Comment: Like CTRL+S. When it creates a folder (with a _files suffix), and downloads the entire page. (I would love to keep the HTML structure, as I already have an app set up to process that output. Not to mention the raw data is not distinguishable.)

Comment: Is additional data on that page loaded dynamically using AJAX? If so there are a couple of related/duplicate questions [here](http://superuser.com/questions/600954/how-do-i-save-a-web-page-in-firefox-the-saved-version-shows-view-previous-com) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/414198/get-current-html-of-page-built-with-ajax-requests), with one answer between them that might perhaps help you too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mozilla Archive Format](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/212/?src=api) firefox addon or [SaveALL!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saveall/?src=api) But i prefer first ...